# Angular 2 RxJS Observable: Retry except on 429 status

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs5

I've composed my Observable (from an HTTP request) to retry on failure. However, I would like to *not* retry if the server responded with `429 Too many requests` error.

The current implementation retries twice, 1 second apart, no matter what.

```
return this.http.get(url,options)
    .retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors.delay(1000).take(2);
    })
    .catch((res)=>this.handleError(res));
```

`errors` is an Observable. How can I get the underlying `Response` object that caused the error? With it I can access the server's status code and only retry if it's not 429:

```
return this.http.get(url,options)
    .retryWhen(errors => {
        if($code == 429) throw errors;
        else return errors.delay(1000).take(2);
    })
.catch((res)=>this.handleError(res));
```

How can I get status code within `retryWhen`?

[**Live demo on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iz9N8LzYIghwqqrstNEN?p=preview)

`Angular 2 rc.6`, `RxJS 5 Beta 11`, `Typescript 2.0.2`

Comment: If an error was thrown because one was received from the server, the error instance should contain `status` and `statusText` properties.

Comment: @cartant yes but how do I get ahold of this instance? If I remove the `retryWhen`, then the instance gets passed to `handleError()` above as an object of class `Response`. But I don't know how to read it during the `retryWhen` logic. As I mentioned in the OP, what that function receives (called `errors` above) is an Observable, not the http `Response` with its `status` and `statusText` properties.

Comment: I would expect any error instances in the errors observable (that were the result of a server error) to contain `status` and `statusText` properties. I'm not familiar with the `retryWhen` operator - hence the comment - but you should be able to get the `status` from the error itself.

Comment: The `status` and `statusText` properties are mentioned/hinted at in an [error-handling](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling) example for the HTTP client.

Comment: @cartant  Notice that those things are available within the error handling function. But `retryWhen` is executed in a different context. let me put a plunker together so we can be specific.

Comment: @cartant I've added a plunker to show the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can compose the handling of 429 errors into the `errors` observable that's passed to `retryWhen`. The errors that are emitted from the `errors` observable will contain a `status` property if they are errors that were received from the server.

If you don't want to retry when 429 errors occur and instead wish to throw an error you could do something like this:

```
return this.http.get(url,options)
    .retryWhen((errors) => {
        return errors
            .mergeMap((error) => (error.status === 429) ? Observable.throw(error) : Observable.of(error))
            .delay(1000)
            .take(2);
    })
    .catch((res) => this.handleError(res));
```

If, instead, you wanted the HTTP observable to complete without emitting either an error or a response, you could simply filter 429 errors.

Comment: Cool. I came back to share my solution (I used `switchMap`) but this works as well.  http://plnkr.co/edit/iz9N8LzYIghwqqrstNEN?p=preview .  Thank Cartant

Comment: Just to note something maybe obvious, after losing few hours with this. retryWhen MUST be before catch! If it's after, it gets called but has empty errors Subject and you can't check status, message, etc in Response.